# how to get only Customer data who is logged in template profile.html but showing all Customer in django

Tags: python, django

models.py ( considering all required data )  how to get only logged in customer but it is showing all Customer

```
class Customer(models.Model):

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100 ,default='')
password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

views.py ( considering all required done )

```
def profile(request):

data= Customer.objects.all()
return render(request,'profile.html' ,{'data':data})
```

profile.html ( considering making urls) and all doing requirement

```
{% if data %}
{% for d in data %}
<h2>{{ d.email }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data= Customer.objects.all()`

data is a list of Customers not a single Customer, so there is no `email` attribute available. Calling `data.email` in the template returns `None`.

You need to loop through `data` in the template.

```
{% if data %}
{% for d in data %}
<h2>{{ d.email }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: yes , when  i do this  {% if data %}
{% for d in data %}
<h2>{{ d.email }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %} this show all the customer email how to get customer who is logged in only